# PHP & SQL (PDO): 1 row with 2 same fields to join in other table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have province table

| province_id | province_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Abra |
| 2 | Bulacan |
| 3 | Cagayan |
| 4 | Dagupa |

and it is connected in 2 fields in person table

| person_id | person_name | currentaddress_province_id | provincialaddress_province_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jepoy | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Jeff | 3 | 4 |

I want to display output like this:

| Name | Current Province | Provincial Province |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jepoy | Abra | Bulacan |
| Jeff | Cagayan | Dagupan |

I tried the below code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM person
LEFT JOIN province ON province.province_id = person.currentaddress_province_id AND person.provincialaddress_province_id
";

$statement = $connect->query($query);
$statement->execute();
$count = $statement->rowCount();
$output = '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Current Province</th><th>Provincial Province</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
if ($count > 0)
{
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row["person_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["province_name"].'</td><td>'.$row["province_name"].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
$output .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $output;
```

but this is the result:

| Name | Current Province | Provincial Province |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jepoy | Abra | Abra |
| Jeff | Cagayan | Cagayan |

Comment: You need to join to the table twice, once for each id.

Comment: You need to JOIN to the province table twice, once for each of the IDs, to get the different values. And give each instance of the fields an alias then you can distinguish them in the PHP array. Also, using INNER JOIN is probably going to be better than LEFT JOIN here (unless there are people who don't have a province record and you still want them to show in the table)

Comment: e.g.     `SELECT 
      per.person_name as name,
      pr1.province_name as current,
      pr2.province_name as provincial
    FROM 
      person per
      INNER JOIN province pr1 
        ON pr1.province_id = per.currentaddress_province_id
      INNER JOIN province pr2
        ON pr2.province_id = per.provincialaddress_province_id`

Then in the PHP you can write

    `$output .= '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["current"].'</td><td>'.$row["provincial"].'</td></tr>';`

Comment: [Solved] Thanks Sir NigelRen and Sir @ADyson your codes is working. Thank you very much.